BottomSheetUIView closing on every fetch of data(pagination)
I have problem in my Swift code, where every time I fetch new data into my BottomSheet, it closes him and swipes him down. I want it to stay open until I close him by swiping him down. I think the problem is in part of the code where fetching didn't fail, because when it fails, it is not closing my bottom sheet down, it just stops loading indicator and prints error in console. But when fetch goes through it closes down sheet and display it. SEE THE VIDEO
Video showing: https://imgur.com/a/HlolQHg
If u need some other parts of code, feel free to ask for it
BottomSheetUIView:

protocol BottomSheetDelegate: AnyObject {
    func bottomSheetDidScroll(offsetY: CGFloat)
    func didSelectBar(with barId: Int) // Delegate metoda za selekciju bara
}

class BottomSheetUIView: UIView, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    weak var delegate: BottomSheetDelegate?
    private var currentPage = 1
        private let itemsPerPage = 10
        private var isFetching = false
        private var allDataFetched = false
    var isExpanded = false
    var sheetMaxHeight: CGFloat = UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.9
    private var isFirstFetch = true

    private var barsData: [BarsListingModel] = [] {
        didSet {
            
//            tableView.reloadData()
            mainLabel.text = "Showing 1 - \(barsData.count) of \(barsData.count) results"
        }
    }

    private lazy var handleView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.9, alpha: 1.0)
        view.layer.cornerRadius = 2.5
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return view
    }()

    private lazy var mainLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Showing 1 - \(barsData.count) of \(barsData.count) results"
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
        label.textColor = .darkGray
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return label
    }()

    private lazy var tableView: UITableView = {
        let tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "BarsTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "BarsTableViewCell")
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        return tableView
    }()

    private let loader: UIActivityIndicatorView = {
        let loader = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .large)
        loader.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        loader.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        loader.hidesWhenStopped = true
        return loader
    }()
    

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupViewHierarchy()
        setupViewAttributes()
        setupLayout()
        setupLoader()

        fetchBarsData(page: currentPage) { [weak self] bars in
            self?.barsData.append(contentsOf: bars)
        }
    }

    private func setupLoader() {
        loader.color = Colors.primaryColor
    }

    private func showLoader() {
        loader.startAnimating()
        loader.isHidden = false
    }

    private func hideLoader() {
        loader.stopAnimating()
        loader.isHidden = true
    }
    
    private func fetchBarsData(page: Int, completion: @escaping ([BarsListingModel]) -> Void) {
        if isFetching || allDataFetched { return }

        isFetching = true
        showLoader()

        let repository = BarsListingRepository()
        let manager = BarsListingManager(repository: repository, mediaRepository: MediaRepository())

        manager.getBars(page: page, perPage: itemsPerPage) { [weak self] models in
            guard let self = self else { return }

            if models.count < self.itemsPerPage {
                self.allDataFetched = true
            }

            // Prepare new data to update `barsData` only after all fetches are complete
            let newBarsData = self.barsData + models
            self.hideLoader()

            // Update `barsData` and reload the table view without triggering animations
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
                    self.barsData = newBarsData
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
                self.isFetching = false // Reset fetching state after the update
            }

        } onFail: { [weak self] error in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            print("Error fetching bars: \(error ?? "Unknown error")")
            print("Harun Begic")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.isFetching = false
                self.hideLoader()
            }
        }
    }
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let offsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        let contentHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height
        let height = scrollView.frame.size.height

        if offsetY > contentHeight - height {
            let currentYPosition = self.frame.origin.y
            print(currentYPosition)
            currentPage += 1

            fetchBarsData(page: currentPage) { _ in
                // Set the BottomSheet position without animation
                self.frame.origin.y = currentYPosition
                
            }
        }
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    private func setupViewHierarchy() {
        self.addSubview(handleView)
        self.addSubview(mainLabel)
        self.addSubview(loader)
        self.addSubview(tableView)
    }

    private func setupViewAttributes() {
        self.backgroundColor = .white
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 15
        self.layer.maskedCorners = [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner]
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.1
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: -1)
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 10
    }
    
    private func extractAutoKeywords(from postContent: String) -> String {
            let stopwords = ["the", "and", "is", "in", "of", "to", "for", "on", "a", "an", "with", "it", "by"]
    
            let words = postContent
                .lowercased()
                .components(separatedBy: .punctuationCharacters)
                .joined()
                .components(separatedBy: " ")
            
            
            let filteredWords = words.filter { word in
                !stopwords.contains(word) && word.count > 3
            }
            
            let wordFrequency = filteredWords.reduce(into: [String: Int]()) { counts, word in
                counts[word, default: 0] += 1
            }
            
            let sortedWords = wordFrequency.sorted { $0.value > $1.value }
            let topWords = sortedWords.prefix(5).map { $0.key }
            
            return topWords.joined(separator: "   ")
        }

    private func setupLayout() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            handleView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor),
            handleView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 8),
            handleView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
            handleView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 5),

            mainLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor),
            mainLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: handleView.bottomAnchor, constant: 8),

            loader.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor),
            loader.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mainLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 8),

            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: loader.bottomAnchor, constant: 8),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }

    // MARK: - UITableViewDataSource

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return barsData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "BarsTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! BarsTableViewCell
        let bar = barsData[indexPath.row]

        cell.barName.text = bar.postTitle
        cell.barDescription.text = bar.postContent
        cell.barCategory.text = self.extractAutoKeywords(from: bar.postContent)

        if let imageUrlString = bar.imageUrl, let imageUrl = URL(string: imageUrlString) {
            DispatchQueue.global().async {
                if let imageData = try? Data(contentsOf: imageUrl) {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        cell.barImage.image = UIImage(data: imageData)
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            cell.barImage.image = nil
        }

        return cell
    }

    // MARK: - UITableViewDelegate

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selectedBar = barsData[indexPath.row]
        delegate?.didSelectBar(with: selectedBar.id)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        if isExpanded {
            self.frame.origin.y = UIScreen.main.bounds.height - sheetMaxHeight
        }
    }
    //    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
//        delegate?.bottomSheetDidScroll(offsetY: scrollView.contentOffset.y)
//    }
}


comment our layoutSubviews and retry

Where are you setting isEpanded? That's what closes the bottom?

@TejaNandamuri I commented layoutSubviews and restarted an app and nothing happens. this isExpanded way is just something I tried and it is not working. I deleted it rn. I think that problem is that something triggers closing when fetch is successful because when error pops out on fetch, it is not closing it.

@user20325868 it doesn't have a use, just old code that was there when I tried to fix it. I removed it not, same thing happens..
